# expected 2 values got one - function

Tags: python

so I'm getting the error not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) on this line: _, name = tagged_contents("head", lines)[0].strip().split(':') and I'm unsure because I've  called the function there ..

This is what one of  file looks like.

Comment: Add the contents of the file, instead of the image please :)

Comment: I've added the text in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tagged_contents` is returning a list to you, which is `one` value.

But you trying to do `_, name = tagged_contents("head", lines)[0].strip().split(':')`, which means you are telling python that `tagged_contents` will return `two` values.

Hence the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`, since you cannot unpack two values from a function which just returns one

Change the function to `name = tagged_contents("head", lines)` and it should work fine

Comment: Okay. I changed that but I also got an error on this line`         _, band_name, amount = line.strip().split(',')` `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)` butI can't just take away amount and band_name because I need those variables..is it not something wrong with my tagged_contents code?

Comment: Same thing,If `line.strip().split(',')` gives you an array of length 3, then this will work otherwise no, also in `tagged_contents` perhaps try to move your `return` out of the for loop and directly within the function

Comment: I tried moving the return loop outside the for loop, but same problem. Also I said above I can't do the same thing for the band_name thing and just put one variable in front because I need band_name and amount variables later.

Comment: The original question was about the error you are gettting, and I have solved it, for the other questions, may I suggest looking at your code and perhaps refactor it, because I can't really tell what is the input is because you did'nt format it with newlines, and didn't tell me what the output is supposed to be @JulieG